# How can I define operations on a template without caring what type it's instantiated with?

Tags: c++, templates

I have inherited a bunch of networking code that defined numerous packet types.  I have to write a bunch of conversion functions that take structs of a certain type, and copy the values into other structs that have the same fields, but in a different order (as part of a convoluted partial platform bit order conversion thing -- don't ask).  Also, I know that there may be better ways of expressing the conversion, etc. below, but I'm not concerned with those at the moment.  Particularly, I cannot make convert take its output variable by reference, because I will be passing in bitfields, and that generates a compiler error.

So there are a bunch of structs like this:

```
struct foo {
   int bar;
   int baz;
};
struct foo_x86 {
   int baz;
   int bar;
};
```

And a bunch of functions like this, to convert between the two:

foo_x86 convert(const foo& in) {
      foo_x86 out;
      out.bar = in.bar;
      out.baz = in.baz;
      return out;
   }

This is all no big deal.  The problem I have is this:  there is also a template struct that looks something like this:

```
template <class T>
struct Packet {
   HeaderType head;
   T          data;
};
```

There are a number of instantiations of this template, using packet types above as the template parameters, for example:

```
struct superfoo {
   Packet<foo> quux;
};
struct superfoo_x86 {
   Packet<foo_x86> quux;
};
```

Now, assuming that there exists a function 
    foo_x86 convert(const foo&);
is there any way to create a template function for handling Packet objects that calls this convert function?

For example, I want something that looks sort of like this:

```
template <class type_1, class type_2>
Packet<type_2> convert(const Packet<type_1>& in) {
   Packet<type_2> out;
   out.head = in.head;
   out.data = convert(in.data);
   return out;
}
```

That would work in a function like:

```
superfoo_x86 convert(const superfoo& in) {
   superfoo_x86 out;
   out.quux = convert(in.quux);
   return out;
}
```

I want to be able to convert Packet objects without caring what type they are instantiated with, and I want to avoid having to declare separate convert functions for every possible Packet instantiation.

Is there anyway to do with with templates in C++?

Comment: You should declare this template function inside your Package template class, so you will not care about the types ;) BR

Comment: +1 for use of so many metasyntactic variables! ;-)  Seriously, though, reading through your samples, this looks fine.  That template should do what you want.  What's the problem you're encountering?  Compiler errors?

Comment: Particularly, the compiler says "error: no matching function for call to `convert(const Packet<foo>&)', because, presumeably, it doesn't recognize that an (automatic?) instantiation of this template function with the types <foo, foo_x86> would do the trick.

Comment: As no function argument involves `type_2`, the compiler can't deduce its type value and automatically resolve `convert` to the template function. You could do it explicitly: `convert<foo, foo_x86>(in.quux)`.  One flaw is that this decouples the super* types and the types of their quux.data members. To fix the flaw, add a typedef to the super* classes so the call becomes `convert<typename superfoo::data_type, typename superfoo_x86::data_type >(in.quux)`, or use a traits template class: `convert<typename traits<superfoo>::data_type, typename traits<superfoo_x86>::data_type >(in.quux)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing something like what outis suggested in the comment on the original question.  First, I created an unspecialized conversion class template, like so:

```
template <class type_1>
struct conversion {};
```

I then threw in a macro for specializing this class (which I believe is like the traits template outis suggested, right?), like so:

```
#define GEN_CON(type_1, type_2) \
    template <> struct conversion<type_1> { typedef type_2 type; }
```

Then, for every conversion function from foo to foo_x86, I added the following macro call in the header after the convert function definition::

```
foo_x86 convert (const foo&);
GEN_CON(foo, foo_x86);
```

This instantiates a conversion template for foo and foo_x86, like so:

```
template <>
struct conversion<foo> { typedef foo_x86 type; }
```

Now, I can refer to conversion::type to get foo_x86.
So, finally, I can create my Packet conversion function, referring to the conversion class, like so:

```
template <class type_1>
Packet< typename conversion<type_1>::type > convert(const Packet<type_1>& in) {
   Packet< typename conversion<type_1>::type > out;
   out.head = convert(in.head);
   out.data = convert(in.data);
   return out;
}
```

This allowed the compiler to resolve references to Packet convert(const Packet& in) just fine, without having pass the template parameters into the call (like da_m_n suggested).

Thanks for all your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure i understand your question correctly.

I suggest you modify your last "convert" function to :

```
template<typename Type1, typename Type2>
void convert(const Type1& in, Type2& out) 
{
   convert(in.quux, out.quux);
}
```

and the one before that :

```
template <class type_1, class type_2>
void convert(const Packet<type_1>& in, Packet<type_2>& out) 
{
   out.head = in.head;
   convert(in.data, out.data);
}
```

And at last, define specializations for fundamental types.

```
template<>
void convert( const int& in, int& out )
{
  out = in;
}
```

To be tested, but it should work fine.

Comment: I should clarify that my convert functions cannot be pass by reference for the out parameter, because some of the fields are bit-fields.

Answer (score 0):

How about calling the conversion like this ?

```
out.data = convert<type_1, type_2>(in.data);
```

Comment: This conversion works, but it means my auto-generating scripts require a special case for the template conversion functions.  I'm hoping to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, would conversion constructors be at all helpful?

```
struct foo_x86;
struct superfoo_x86;

struct foo {
   int bar;
   int baz;
   explicit foo(const foo_x86& from);
};
struct foo_x86 {
   int baz;
   int bar;
   explicit foo_x86(const foo& from) : bar(from.bar), baz(from.baz) {}
};
foo::foo(const struct foo_x86& from) : bar(from.bar), baz(from.baz) {}

template <class T>
struct Packet {
   HeaderType head;
   T          data;
   template <class S>
     explicit Packet(const Packet<S>& from) : head(from.head), data(from.data) {}
};
struct superfoo {
   Packet<foo> quux;
   explicit superfoo(const superfoo_x86& from);
};
struct superfoo_x86 {
   Packet<foo_x86> quux;
   explicit superfoo_x86(const superfoo& from) : quux(from.quux) {}
};
superfoo::superfoo(const superfoo_x86& from) : quux(from.quux) {}
```

It seems they'd solve the problem with automatically deducing template arguments. It might make sense for you to skip the `explicit` specifiers.

Comment: That's a good idea, I hadn't thought of it.  However, I am trying to avoid modifying the original structs as much as I can.  I ended up with a different solution, see my own answer.